# How to make the first item in a lazy column clickable and make the rest unclickable

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

How to make the first item in a lazy column clickable and make the rest unclickable.

for example if I have a list of tasks to complete, enable first item only which is not completed

you have to complete tasks one at a time

```
     
        LazyColumn(
            modifier.padding(top = 40.dp),
        ) {

            itemsIndexed(
                items = todayRoute.sortedBy { it.sequence },
            ) { index, item ->

                Row(
                    modifier = modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .height(90.dp)
                        .padding(12.dp)
                        .clickable(
                            enabled = item.completed == "0" &&
                                    item.arrived == "0" &&
                                    item.missed == "0"
                        ) {

                          })
                       {

                 }
               }
              }
```

Comment: `enabled = index == 0` ?

Comment: thanks, so once the first item is completed, do I move it to the back of the list so  the next task is clickable?

Answer (score 0):

Use Hashmap like this

As soon as you get all the item call `replaceAll`.
When the item is completed, call `taskCompleted`

```kotlin
class TaskViewModel {

    private var _taskStatus = MutableStateFlow<HashMap<String, Boolean>>(hashMapOf())
    val taskStatus = _taskStatus.asStateFlow()
    
    fun taskCompleted(item: Task) {
         _taskStatus.replace(item.id, true)
    }

    fun replaceAll(tasks: List<Task>) {
        _taskStatus.value.clear()
        tasks.forEach {
            _taskStatus.value[it.id] = it.completed
        }
    }

    private fun MutableStateFlow<HashMap<String, Boolean>>.replace(key: String, value: Boolean) {
        val helper = HashMap<String, Boolean>(this.value)
        helper[key] = value
        this.value = helper
    }
}
```

On UI, Adjust according to your need

```kotlin
val taskStatus by remember { viewModel.taskStatus }.collectAsState()

LazyColumn {
    itemsIndexed(todayRoute) { item, index ->
        Row(modifier = Modifier.clickable(
                enabled = if (index > 0)
                     taskStatus[index - 1] ?: false
                else
                     true
            )
        ) {}
    }
}
```